# Correct way to close DialogFragment when using Navigation component?

Tags: android, navigation, android-architecture-components

I am using the Navigation component to show a `DialogFragment` (`<dialog...>...</dialog>` in the `navigation.xml`) and want to know what's the recommended way to close the Dialog. I tried myself and got the following results:

1) `dismiss()`in `DialogFragment`: seems to work fine

2) `findNavController().navigateUp()`: seems to work fine

3) `findNavController().navigate(MyDialogFragmentDirections.actionMyDialogFragmentToMyNormalFragment())`: works, but loads a fresh version of the target destination, so depending on the use case this might not be what one wants to have.

Note: My use case is that `MyNormalFragment`uses `MyDialogFragment`to get some input, so after `MyDialogFragment`is shown, I need to get back to the already existing instance of `MyNormalFragment`.

So for me, only 1) or 2) is correct. Now I am wondering, is there any difference between 1) and 2) ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Both 1) and 2) end up doing the same thing the end, but 2) is always a safer option.

When you call `dismiss()`, the `DialogFragment` is dismissed and the `DialogFragment` is stopped (it receives a callback to `onStop()`). This triggers the [listener in `DialogFragmentNavigator`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:navigation/navigation-fragment/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/fragment/DialogFragmentNavigator.java;l=58), which then updates the `NavController`'s state by calling `popBackStack()`.

`dismiss()` however, is an asynchronous operation (as seen in the [`DialogFragment` source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:fragment/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment.java;l=324) - you'll note it does not use `commitNow()`, etc). Therefore if you were to check what destination you are on from the `NavController.getCurrentDestination()`, you'd see that you're still on the dialog destination, despite having triggered the dismissal.

`navigateUp()`, on the other hand, goes directly to the NavController. Since you have another destination on your back stack (the one under the `DialogFragment`), the [`NavController` source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:navigation/navigation-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/NavController.java;l=397) shows that `navigateUp()` just calls `popBackStack()` - the same operation that `dismiss()` was eventually triggering.

However, when it is the `NavController` that is driving the operation, `NavController` updates its state synchronously. This means that immediately after you call `navigateUp()`, it will have updated its `getCurrentDestination()` and internal state in addition to calling through to [`DialogFragmentNavigator`'s `popBackStack()`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:navigation/navigation-fragment/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/fragment/DialogFragmentNavigator.java;l=88), which is what calls through to `dismiss()` (removing the observer mentioned above to prevent double dismissals).

Therefore calling `navigateUp()` is always the safer choice since it ensures that the `NavController` is synchronously updated to the correct state, rather than rely on `FragmentManager`'s asynchronous timing (which may mean that additional click events are received during that time period due to multi-touch, etc.).

Calling `navigate()` with an action that has an `app:destination` on it will navigate to a new instance of the destination, which would not be appropriate for returning back to your previous instance.

Comment: For me dismiss is not working, Current destination of navhostfragment is not updating. And I want to know if my dialog fragment is launching from navigation graph and without nav graph based on some condition then can I call findNavController().navigateUp()?

Comment: @Himanshu I have the same issue, being difficult to work.

Comment: So if I have a cancel and save button, and a dismiss even when touching outside the dialog, where do I call navigateUp? My problem right now is that any of these actions remove the back button that was on my toolbar.

Comment: @Chucky - assuming your cancel and save buttons are from an `AlertDialog`, then those buttons already internally dismiss the dialog, same as tapping outside the Dialog. Navigation still listens for those events and updates the Navigation state for you. If you `navigate()` as part of that cancel/save button though, I'd make sure that action also pops the dialog (i.e., by using `popUpTo`) - that will ensure that the dialog pop is recorded first, before you navigate to a new destination.

Comment: Thanks Hannibal. I suspected this was the case that it was already handled. But I'm still not sure why the dismiss makes my back button on the fragment underneath disappear?

Comment: Method `.navigateUp()` only works with `app:popUpTo`, when it's a global destination.