# Not able to open dialog again after image selection from it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-architecture-navigation, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have a Fragment where I opening bottom dialog

```
private void openImageDialog() {
        NavController navController = findNavController(view);
        Timber.d("%s", navController.getCurrentDestination());
        navController.navigate(SettingUpProfileFragmentDirections.openImageDialog(resourceFile));
}
```

And on BottomSheetDialogFragment I have

```
private void openGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_PICK, EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}
```

After returning on dialog I just dismiss dialog like this

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
         dismiss();
     }
}
```

and when I am trying to open dialog from Fragment again I get the next exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.xxx:id/openImageDialog cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.xxx:id/editProfilePhotoDialog)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:938)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:875)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:861)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1150)
        at com.xxx.ui.fragment.SettingUpProfileFragment.openImageDialog(SettingUpProfileFragment.java:143)
        at com.xxx.ui.fragment.SettingUpProfileFragment.onProfileImageClick(SettingUpProfileFragment.java:130)
        at com.xxx.ui.fragment.SettingUpProfileFragment.lambda$onViewCreated$4$SettingUpProfileFragment(SettingUpProfileFragment.java:96)
        at com.xxx.ui.fragment.-$$Lambda$SettingUpProfileFragment$2Q5hfVos3CTEjzzPhfVwb1h-ZBs.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Log from `openImageDialog()` method shows that I'm still on dialog fragment
`D/SettingUpProfileFragment: Destination(com.xxx:id/editProfilePhotoDialog)`.

I have the idea that I'm still on dialog because of opening gallery from it but have no idea how it can impact navigation. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Replaced `dismiss()` with `Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(), R.id.mainNavigationFragment).popBackStack()` and it fixed issue. But still curios why `dismiss()` is not working as expected.

Comment: Find an explanation in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61035058/correct-way-to-close-dialogfragment-when-using-navigation-component. Close question